# Converting an image instance (file) to an array (python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have an image sequence and I am trying to run a script on a specific frame. I need to switch to this frame and convert it to an array. However, I am unable to as the frame is an instance `<TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16 size=512x512 at 0x104A0C998>`. How can I convert this instance to an array? I have already used numpy.array and it does not work.
Thank you!

```
prot=Image.open("F23BN.tif")
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(dna):
    if frame==16:
        frame.convert('L')
        print frame.mode, frame.format #I checked the format and it is still in the Instance format
```

Comment: Please show us what you did so far. If I remember correctly you can do it with [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Comment: prot=Image.open("F23BN.tif")
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(dna):
    if frame==16:
        frame.convert('L')
        print frame.mode, frame.format #I checked the format and it is still in the Instance format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand your question, you are trying to get access to the binary data contained in a tiff image.  As Dav1d suggested you can do it in PIL.  I tested the following in python 2.6.5

```
import Image
import numpy

im = Image.open('Tiff.tif')

imarray = numpy.array(im)
print imarray.shape, im.size   #these agree
```

For a more difficult way to do this, you can open the file just as you would any other file.  In the code snippet, I assume that your file isn't too big to just load into memory all at once.

```
im = open('Tiff.tif','r')
image_data = im.read()
im.close()

#lets look at the first few characters
for char in image_data[:64]:  
    print ord(char),  #need to use ord so we can see the number
```

With the data in the string image_data, you are free to turn it into any other data type you wish.  However, this may not be useful right away.  First of all the data is binary.  You will need to decipher it using the tiff specification.  For example, the first 8 bytes are a header.

More details:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf