# How to perform PCA on a folder of tiff images?

Tags: python, image, numpy, pca, tiff

I am trying to perform PCA in python 3 on a set of tiff images that are located in a single folder. I have already referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130255/load-tiff-image-as-numpy-array?lq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224362/principal-component-analysis-pca-in-python) but am still unsure on what the error is. All of the tiff images are the same size.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import glob
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

images = [misc.imread(path) for path in glob.glob("path/*.tif")]
images = np.asarray(images)
print(images.size)
pca = PCA(150)
pca.fit(images)
```

I first upload them all into a np.array and try to perform PCA, but I keep getting the error below.

> File
>   "Users/.../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py",
>   line 538, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Why do I keep getting this error and how should I perform PCA on these tiff images?

Comment: This images have same size?

Comment: as for me it can works with 1-dimensional array - array with single values - but you have 2-dimensional array or even n-dimensional if you get that every image has 3-dimensions (x, y, RGB). And these dimensions create `sequence` in array. OR maybe you have to flatten every image so it would use only one dimension ?

Comment: if I use `imread(path).flatten()` and `PCA()` without 150 then it starts working for me. I don't need even `np.asarray()`

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota yes they all have the same size